# Northwind - How many countries one shipper handled in one year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help with my shipping query.
I need to count, how many different countries one shipping company delivered to in last year. My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT CompanyName, Count(o.CountryID) as Shipments, o.CountryID as Countries
FROM Shippers s
INNER JOIN Orders o ON s.ShipperID = o.ShipVia
WHERE DATEPART(year, o.OrderDate)=1997
GROUP BY CompanyName, o.CountryID
ORDER BY Shipments DESC;
```

It gives me list of Companies, How many times this company shipper to country with CountryID.

```
United Package  26  9
United Package  26  20
Speedy Express  23  9
Speedy Express  19  20
United Package  17  4
Speedy Express  16  4
```

What I need is to count how many distinctive countries one shipping company delivered to. So for example it should give me:

```
United Package 120 4
Speedy Express 90  3
```

United Package send 120 orders to 4 different countries. 
How can I change my query to get that result?

Comment: Add Complete data because it's not clear that `United Package` having  `120 shipments`  and `4 Country`

Comment: @JayShankarGupta It was just an example result. I need Company Name, number of Shipments in total, and Number of how many different countries they've shipped to in total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CompanyName, SUM(Shipments) AS Shipments,COUNT(DISTINCT Countries) AS Countries
FROM
(
SELECT CompanyName, Count(o.CountryID) as Shipments, o.CountryID as Countries
FROM Shippers s
INNER JOIN Orders o ON s.ShipperID = o.ShipVia
WHERE DATEPART(year, o.OrderDate)=1997
GROUP BY CompanyName, o.CountryID
) AS T
GROUP BY CompanyName
ORDER BY Shipments DESC
```

Comment: It throws an error "The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified."

Comment: Thanks, it works now and I think the result is correct!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

```
SELECT s.CompanyName, Count(*) as Shipments,
       COUNT(DISTINCT o.CountryID) as Countries
FROM Shippers s INNER JOIN
     Orders o
     ON s.ShipperID = o.ShipVia
WHERE o.OrderDate >= '1997-01-01' AND o.OrderDate < '1998-01-01'
GROUP BY s.CompanyName
ORDER BY Shipments DESC;
```

Notes:

- Qualify *all* column names, especially in a query that has more than one table reference.
- Don't use `datepart()`.  That prevents the use of indexes.  Instead, do direct comparisons on dates.
- `COUNT(DISTINCT)` appears to do what you want.